# What memory limit for Apple Notifications service extension

Tags: ios, xcode, unusernotificationcenter

I've implemented notifications extension and now try to debug my code, but without any success.
I tried several approaches how to handle it, for example [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140158/debug-notification-extensions/)

When I "attach to process ...", I just see "waiting to attach" message on desired process. If I send push notification to invoke my extension, it just crashes

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

Is it possible that OS just close my extension, because it uses to much memory or it has too big size (~.appex = 20mb), but I can't find guidelines about extension size/number of files, etc.

Any suggestions, help?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like that there is a memory limit for `Notification Service Extension`. Someone said [it may be 5mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775269/terminated-due-to-memory-issue). And someone said that the limit is [5mb in ObjC, or 15mb in Swift](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60632).

Due to the limit, I remove all 3rd party libraries in `Notification Service Extension`.

Answer (score 3):

I disabled the address sanitizer and undefined behavior sanitizer in the main app's scheme and the service extension loads ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked `Notification Service Extension`, Here you can see what is memory limit as per latest iOS update.

[image]

As per Xcode debugging 24 MB is notification extension memory limit.